# Verify that user input is one of several allowed words

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I am having trouble with this line of code, which is meant to check if user input matches the given options.

```
set /p "myVar=---> " 
echo %myVar%|findstr /ix "red:Red:blue:Blue">nul && ( 
 echo %myVar% matched 
 ) || ( 
 echo %myVar% not matched 
 )
```

Is there a way I can go it like the above or any other way?

Comment: It's absolutely unclear to me what you are asking. To get single key user input have a look at [choice.exe /?](http://ss64.com/cmd/choice.html)

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: my mistake, please see above for update on issue

Comment: It would have been courteous to have commented to any answerers who had answered your initial inaccurate question so that they were aware that their solutions were no longer valid and that they'd wasted their time and effort; _(with perhaps an apology)_!

Comment: Are you sure that the only allowed words are `Red` and `Blue`? because if someone creates a solution where the selections cannot easily be changed by you, will you just ignore their answer or change the question again?

Comment: read my answer again. Just out of curiousity: why did you insert colons? My answer is still valid (if it's `a e i o u` or `red green blue` doesn't matter).

Comment: By the way: changing your question to a degree, which invalidates any  answers (which are working for the original question) is a bad habit and not well received. You should have asked a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the fact that `for /F` returns an exit code of `1` in case of zero iterations:

```cmd
set /P VAR="Enter something: " || ((echo Empty input!) & exit /B)
(for /F "delims=AaEeIiOoUuYy eol=y" %%K in ("%VAR%") do rem/) && (
    echo No match found!
) || (
    echo Match encountered.
)
```

If the input consists only of characters listed after `delims=`, the `for /F` loop does not iterate and returns an exit code of `1`; the command behind `&&` only executes in case the exit code is `0`, the command behind `||` only executes in case the exit code is not `0`.
If no input is provided, `set /P` sets the exit code to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of what you want to do. I have not tested in DOS since I do not have any VM (or very old computer) right here, but IIRC this should work in plain DOS as well.

```
@echo off
if %var% == A GOTO :anything
if %var% == E GOTO :anything
if %var% == I GOTO :anything
if %var% == O GOTO :anything
if %var% == U GOTO :anything
if %var% == Y GOTO :anything
goto end
:anything
echo anything
:end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, `choice` is your best friend here. But if you want to do it without `choice` (it isn't available in all Windows versions):

```
set /p "myVar=---> "
echo %myVar%|findstr /ix "a e i o u y">nul && (
  echo %myVar% matched
) || (
  echo %myVar% not matched
)
```

It asks for input and checks if it is exactly one of the characters from the list, ignoring capitalization.